# Not opening IDE as Admin causes FileStream throw access to the path is denied exception

Tags: c#, filestream

As the title says, if I open Visual Studio IDE as Admin, FileStream works just fine. But if I don't run as admin, it gives Access to the path 'C:\\ABCD.ddthp' is denied. But if I select a folder inside the C directory it works fine. For example if the path is 'C:\ABCFolder\ABCD.ddthp' it works fine. Here is my code. Is there any work around for this or should the IDE be opened as Admin.

```
 try
            {
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }

           //The following line causes an exception.

                using (var stream = new FileStream(path,
                    FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write).Encrypt())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);
                        jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                        protocolJObject.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
                    }
                }
                return ReturnCodes.Success;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                SystemDebugLogLogger.LogError(ex, "Protocol: WriteJson");
                returnValue = ReturnCodes.FileAccessDenied;
            }
```

Comment: That just means you need to run as admin to write to the root of your C: drive.

Comment: The OS requires administrative privileges to write files in the root of your system disk. Just don't write file there

Comment: I don't understand why a down vote. I edited my question to ask if there exists a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround would be to not write directly to the `C:` drive, or any other location that requires administrative access. Depending on the purpose of the file, there are usually three candidate locations:

1. The temp folder, for files that you don't need to save
2. The AppData folder, for files that your application will need and which may be different for different users
3. The install location for your application

You can get these folders like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Create your own file name
    var fileName = "MyAppData.txt";

    // Get temp path
    var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();

    // Get AppData path and add a directory for your .exe
    // To use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly, you need to add: using System.Reflection
    var appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    var exeName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
    var appDataForThisExe = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, exeName);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appDataForThisExe);

    // Get the path where this .exe lives
    var exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(
        new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);

    // Now you can join your file name with one of the above paths
    // to construct the full path to the file you want to write
    var tempFile = Path.Combine(tempPath, fileName);
    var appDatFile = Path.Combine(appDataForThisExe, fileName);
    var exePathFile = Path.Combine(exePath, fileName);

    Console.WriteLine($"Temp file path:\n {tempFile}\n");
    Console.WriteLine($"AppData file path:\n {appDatFile}\n");
    Console.WriteLine($"Exe location file path:\n {exePathFile}");

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your user account doesn't have permission to write to the C:\ drive of your computer but admin does.

You can give yourself permission by right clicking on the C:\ drive in windows explorer, select properties and then the security tab and give your account write access.

Alternatively, use a better location